# SC.exe config <servicename> obj= LocalSystem is giving error

Tags: windows-services

The command `sc.exe config <servicename> obj= LocalSystem` results in the following error:

> ```
> The account name is invalid or does not exist,
> or the password is invalid for the account name specified.
> ```

I want to create batch file to change a particular service to *LocalSystem* but the above command does not work. I can set *LocalSystem* via `services.msc` without problems.

Thanks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For *LocalSystem* an empty password must be provided:

```
sc.exe config <servicename> obj= LocalSystem password= ""
```

Comment: On my computer (Windows 7 Professional), `sc.exe config <servicename> obj= .\LocalSystem` (without the dummy 'password=' parameter) does work.

Comment: Windows 7 and later can omit `password= ""`, whereas (IIRC, but am uncertain that) Windows Vista and Windows XP both require it.

Answer (score 1):

try this...

```
sc config **Myservice** obj= LocalSystem password= ""
```

Answer (score 0):

As written in:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/ms684190(v=vs.85).aspx

If you specify the LocalSystem account in a call to the CreateService or ChangeServiceConfig function, any password information you provide is ignored.